# odd padding/margin showing in firefox/chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I'm trying to make a list showing horizontally with a 1px border on the right except for the last one. For some reason, on chrome there is a little margin at the bottom but it does not show on Firefox. But on Firefox, there is a margin on the right(last li element) which does not show on chrome. Any ideas on what it could be? I honestly can't find it and I've been trying to fix this for a while now..

```css
body {
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica neue Light", sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#menuBar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
#logo {
  padding: 5px 0 0 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 120%;
  float: left;
}
#buttonDiv {
  float: right;
  padding: 5px 10px 0 0;
}
#runButton {
  font-size: 120%;
}
#toggles {
  width: 256px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  height: 29px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}
#toggles li {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 5px 7px;
}
li:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
.selected {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="wrapper">

    <div id="menuBar">

      <div id="logo">
        Website Visualizer
      </div>

      <div id="buttonDiv">

        <button id="runButton">Run Code</button>

      </div>

      <ul id="toggles">

        <li class="toggle selected">HTML</li>
        <li class="toggle ">CSS</li>
        <li class="toggle ">JavaScript</li>
        <li class="toggle selected" style="border:none">Result</li>

      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
```

edit: hey guys i fixed it. So basically i removed the border from the UL element and just added a border all around each individual li element.

Comment: Try adding `*{ box-sizing:border-box; }` to your CSS.

Comment: Try with `display: inline-block;` in the item lists.

Comment: adding box-sizing:border-box to my li elements and it's still the same. I also tried with the entire ul div but it's the same as well. inline-block doesn't work either.

Comment: Your problem it´s because of the ul fixed width!!!!

Comment: @Legues i have a width of 256px in my ul though don't i?

Comment: I just wanted to show you why you are having the problem. And what i told you was the problem was the fixed width. Maybe your solution is try to let the items determine the width. Or if your UI says that your ul has a fixed with, maybe you can setup  a % width to the Li´s

Answer (score 0):

On your #toggles remove:

```
#toggles {
    /*width: 256px;*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    height: 29px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Your problem it´s because of fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code in `#toggles` as follows:

```
#toggles {
    /* width: 256px; */
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    height: 29px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
}
```

By removing the width on the container, you make sure that the width of the container is equal to the sum of all the widths of its children.

Then change your definition of `#toggles li`as follows:

```
#toggles li {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 0 7px;
  line-height: 29px;
}
```

By setting the `line-height`to the container height, you make sure the children will occupy the full vertical space while aligning the text vertically (if you don't care about vertical alignment, you can also set `height: 100%;`)